# Smallest window (substring) that has both uppercase and corresponding lowercase characters

Tags: string, algorithm

I was asked the following question in an onsite interview:

> A string is considered "balanced" when every letter in the string appears both in uppercase and lowercase. For e.g., `CATattac` is balanced (`a`, `c`, `t` occur in both cases), while `Madam` is not (`a`, `d` only appear in lowercase).  Write a function that, given a string, returns the shortest balanced substring of that string.  For e.g.,: 
> “azABaabza” should return “ABaab” 
> “TacoCat” should return -1 (not balanced) 
> “AcZCbaBz” should returns the entire string

Doing it with the brute force approach is trivial - calculating all the pairs of substrings and then checking if they are balanced, while keeping track of the size and starting index of the smallest one.

How do I optimize?  I have a strong feeling it can be done with a sliding-window/two-pointer approach, but I am not sure how.  When to update the pointers of the sliding window?

Edit: Removing the sliding-window tag since this is not a sliding-window problem (as discussed in the comments).

Comment: How can TacoCat not be balanced when it has 'TC' and 'tc' ?

Comment: @Ezani, because in between you would encounter an `a` and `o` that don't have corresponding uppercase letters.  Note that the question asks for a _substring_.

Comment: What is the target of optimizing? brute force can be optimized to O(N^2) will that be enough?

Comment: I don't think this is related to two-pointers/sliding window as a string is balanced does not imply the string containing the balanced string is balanced

Comment: I think you mean *the longest balanced substring*, and not *the shortest balanced substring*? Otherwise the trivial answer is always the empty string.

Comment: @AnsonYeung, what do you mean?  Could you please elaborate?  IMO two-pointers/sliding window does not need a substring of a string to satisfy the property - in fact, if it did, then that substring would be what we are looking for.

Comment: two-pointers would require that if the solution to be found is included inside a boundary, we will know the solution exist inside the boundaries. In this problem, we can't

Comment: @AnsonYeung, sorry, but how is this any different from, say, [Minimum Window Substring](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-window-substring/)?  The way I am looking at it, only the condition for the contents of the window is different.

Comment: @Someone In the question you provided. If a substring meet the requirement, any string consisting of that substring will meet the requirement too so two-pointers can be applied. For example "abc" meet the requirement if t is "ab" and so do any string containing "abc" such as "d**abc**ce"

Comment: However, in your question, if a substring is balanced does not imply the string containing the balanced substring is balanced

Comment: @AnsonYeung, consider s = "ADOBECODE**BANC**", t = "ABC"; Now if we modify `t` to be just "AB" instead, this new `t` can be found in our previous result (**BA**NC).  That's why a two pointer algorithm was applicable in that case.  Is that what you are saying?

Comment: No, I didn't mention changing the `t`, its more like s = "ADOBECODE**BANC**" implies s = "ADOBECOD**EBANC**" will work.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Yes, because then that would have helped move the pointer from `E` to `B`.  That is what was confusing me here - I wasn't sure how to move the pointers.

Comment: @AnsonYeung, should this condition **_always_** be satisfied for two-pointer/sliding window to work?

Comment: @Someone I can't answer you with a 100% certainty. It's best to ask that question in another post. However, I would personally say yes as far as I know about the two-pointers method.

Comment: @AnsonYeung, cool, thank you!  Appreciate your guidance! :)

Answer (score 3):

Due to the special property of string. There is only 26 uppercase letters and 26 lowercase letters.
We can loop every 26 letter `j` and denote the minimum length for any substrings starting from position `i` to find matches for uppercase and lowercase letter `j` be `len[i][j]`
Demo C++ code:

```cpp
string s = "CATattac";
// if len[i] >= s.size() + 1, it denotes there is no matching
vector<vector<int>> len(s.size(), vector<int>(26, 0));
for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
    int upperPos = s.size() * 2;
    int lowerPos = s.size() * 2;
    for (int j = s.size() - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
        if (s[j] == 'A' + i) {
            upperPos = j;
        } else if (s[j] == 'a' + i) {
            lowerPos = j;
        }
        len[j][i] = max(lowerPos - j + 1, upperPos - j + 1);
    }
}
```

We also keep track of the count of characters.

```cpp
// cnt[i][j] denotes the number of characters j in substring s[0..i-1]
// cnt[0][j] is always 0
vector<vector<int>> cnt(s.size() + 1, vector<int>(26, 0));
for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 26; ++j) {
        cnt[i + 1][j] = cnt[i][j];
        if (s[i] == 'A' + j || s[i] == 'a' + j) {
            ++cnt[i + 1][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Then we can loop over s.

```cpp
int m = s.size() + 1;
for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
    bool done = false;
    int minLen = 1;
    while (!done && i + minLen <= s.size()) {
        // execute at most 26 times, a new character must be added to change minLen
        int prevMinLen = minLen;
        done = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < 26 && i + minLen <= s.size(); ++j) {
            if (cnt[i + minLen][j] - cnt[i][j] > 0) {
                // character j exists in the substring, have to find pair of it
                minLen = max(minLen, len[i][j]);
            }
        }
        if (prevMinLen != minLen) done = false;
    }
    // find overall minLen
    if (i + minLen <= s.size())
        m = min(m, minLen);
    cout << minLen << '\n';
}
```

Output: (if `i + minLen <= s.size()`, it is valid. Otherwise substring doesn't exist if starting at that position)
The invalid output difference is due to how the array `len` is generated.

```
8
4
15
14
13
12
11
10
```

I'm not sure whether there is a simpler solution but it is the best I could think of right now.
Time complexity: O(N) with a constant of 26 * 26

Comment: Could you please provide the entire code? That would help me understand it better. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: @Someone you can just concatenate the 3 code directly.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I previously had O(`n`log(`n`)) due to a unnecessary binary search.

I thought of a solution, which is *technically* O(`n`), where `n` is the length of the string, but the constant is pretty large.

For simplicity's sake, let's consider an analogous situation with only two letters, `A` and `B` (and their lowercase counterparts), and let `l` be the size of the alphabet for future reference. I worked on an example string `ABabBaaA`.

We start by computing the prefix counts of the number of occurrences of each letter. In this case, we get

```
i: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
----------------------------
A: 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2
a: 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3
B: 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2
b: 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

This way, assuming we are indexing the string starting from `1` (for implementation's sake you can add an extra character to the beginning, like a dollar sign `$`), we can get the number of occurrences of each letter on any substring in constant time (or rather -- in O(`l`), but in my case `l` is set to `2` and in your case `l = 26` so technically this is constant time).

OK now we prepare arrays / vectors /  queues of character indices, so if the character `A` appears on indices `1` and `8`, the structure will consist of `1` and `8`. We get

```
A: 1, 8
a: 3, 6, 7
B: 2, 5
b: 4
```

What is important, is that in arrays and vectors, we can look up certain "lowest element greater than" in amortized constant time by discarding indices which are smaller than every index one by one.

Now, the algorithm. Starting at each (left) index greater than `0`, we will find the earliest  right index for which the substring bound by `[left_index, right_index]` is balanced. We do that as follows:

0. Start with `left_index = right_index = i` for `i = 1, ..., n`.
1. Read the array of prefix counts for `right_index` and subtract the prefix counts for `left_index - 1` receiving the counts for the substring `[left_index, right_index]`. Find any letter, which fails the "balance" check. If there is none, you found the shortest balanced substring starting at `left_index`.
2. Find the first occurrence of the "missing" letter, greater than `left_index`. Set `right_index` to the index of that occurrence. Go to step 1 keeping the modified `right_index`.

For example: starting with `left_index = right_index = 1` we see that the number of occurrences of each letter in the substring is `1, 0, 0, 0`, so `a` fails the check. The earliest occurrence of `a` is `3`, so we set `right_index = 3`. We go back to step 1 receiving a new array of occurrences: `1, 1, 1, 0`. Now `b` fails the check, and its earliest occurrence greater than `1` is `4`, so we set `right_index` to `4`. We go to step 1 receiving an array of occurrences `1, 1, 1, 1`, which passes the balance check.

Another example: starting with `left_index = right_index = 2` we get in step 1 an array of occurrences `0, 0, 1, 0`. Now `b` fails the check. The earliest occurrence of `b` greater than `left_index` is `4`, so we set `right_index` to `4`. Now we get an array of occurrences `0, 1, 1, 1`, so `A` fails the check. The earliest occurrence of `A` greater than `left_index` is `8`, so we set `right_index` to that. Now, the array of occurrences is `2-1, 3-0, 2-0, 1-0`, which is `1, 3, 2, 1` and it passes the balance check.

Ultimately we will find the shortest balanced substring to be `bB` with `left_index = 4`.

The complexity of this algorithm is O(`nl^2`) because: we start at `n` different indices and we perform a maximum of `l` lookups (for `l` different letters which can fail the check) in O(`1`). For each lookup, we have to calculate `l` differences of prefix sums. But as `l` is constant (albeit it may be large, like 26), this simplifies to O(`n`).

Comment: Nice explanation, but I did not follow your second eg.: "left_index = right_index = 2 we get in step 1 an array of occurrences `0,0,1,0`.  Now b fails the check."  How?  Shouldn't we get `1,0,1,0` instead (and then the check fails at `a`)?

Comment: Also, how does it ensure we find the "shortest" balanced string?  If I understand correctly, we will have to iterate over the entire length of the string and run the algo for each index as `left_index=right_index=i`.  Right?

Comment: I believe the time complexity will be still O(Nl^2) as it is basically the same as my algorithm? Read the array of prefix counts will take O(l) and there will be at most O(l) loops of reading prefix counts.

Comment: @Someone To answer your first comment: we receive `0,0,1,0` by subtracting the `left_index-1`-th prefix sums from the `right_index`-th prefix sums. We receive `1-1,0-0,1-0,0-0`, which is `0,0,1,0`. Now `b` fails the check because the number of occurrences for `B` is non-zero, but the number of occurrences for `b` is zero. So `b` is missing, so `b` fails the check. `A` and `a` satisfy the check because the number of occurrences is zero for both.

Comment: @Someone To answer your second comment: yes, we iterate over the whole string and for each starting position (`left_index`) we find the shortest substring which is balanced. Thus, after finding the shortest for every starting position, we pick the shortest out of those, and that is the overall shortest one.

If you are asking why finding the shortest for each starting position works, that is because the check must be satisfied by all letters, and for each "bad" letter we find the left-most `right_index` which makes the letter satisfy the check.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a recursive approach to this; I'm not sure what it's time complexity is though.

The idea is we check what characters in the string are present in both their lower and upper form formats. For any characters that aren't given in both forms, we replace them with a space ' '. We then split the remaining string on ' ' into a list.

In the first case, if we have only one string left after it- we return it's length.

In the second case, if we have no characters left, we return -1.

In the third case, if we have more than one string left, we re-evaluate each of the strings sub-lengths and return the length of the longest string we then evaluate.

```py
    from collections import Counter
    
    def findMutual(s):
        lower = dict(Counter( [x for x in s if x.lower() == x] ))
        upper = dict(Counter( [x for x in s if x.upper() == x] ))
    
        mutual = {}
    
        for charr in lower:
            if charr.upper() in upper:
                mutual[charr] = upper[charr.upper()] + lower[charr]
    
        matching_charrs = ''.join([x if x.lower() in mutual else ' ' for x in s ]).split()
        print(s)
        print(matching_charrs)
        return matching_charrs
    
    
    
    def smallestSubstring(s):
    
        matching_charrs = findMutual(s)
    
        if len(matching_charrs) == 1:
            return(len(matching_charrs[0]))
        elif len(matching_charrs) == 0:
            return(-1)
        else:
            list_lens = []
            for i in matching_charrs:
                list_lens.append(smallestSubstring(i))
            return max(list_lens)                
    
    print(smallestSubstring('azABaabza'))
    print(smallestSubstring('dAcZCbaBz'))
    print(smallestSubstring('TacoCat'))
    print(smallestSubstring('Tt'))
    print(smallestSubstring('T'))
    print(smallestSubstring('TaCc'))
```